# How to solve $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x^2 + x^3} \sin \frac{\pi}{x}$ using squeeze Theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I solve $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x^2 + x^3} \sin \frac{\pi}{x}$ using squeeze Theorem?

My book only teaches me the simplest use of the Theorem. I have no idea what should I do with a function as complex as this...

I know I have to start with:

$$ -1 \le \sin \frac{\pi}{x} \le 1$$

But what do I do next?

Comment: Multiply both sides for $\sqrt{x^2 + x^3}$

Comment: It seems as if at least fifty-percent of questions posted here misuse the word "solve" in this way.  One solves problems.  One solves equations.  One does not "solve" expressions; one _evaluates_ them.

Comment: @rlartiga : By "both" I surmise that you mean "all three".

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes lol :-)

Answer (score 7):

Then you could say
$$-\sqrt{x^{2}+x^{3}}\le \sqrt{x^{2}+x^{3}} \, \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\le \sqrt{x^{2}+x^{3}}.$$
The outermost functions approach the desired limit, and so by the Squeeze Theorem, you get the desired result.

Comment: Which would be 0, right?

Comment: @user3347814 Yes!

Answer (score 3):

You have $$-1 \leq \sin \frac{\pi}{x} \leq 1$$

Multiply it by what is left:

$$-\sqrt{x^2 + x^3} \leq \sqrt{x^2 + x^3} \sin \frac{\pi}{x} \leq \sqrt{x^2 + x^3}$$

What happens when $x \to 0$? The limit we want will be *squeezed* between which values?